# New Website on New Server displaying 404 from old site on old server

Tags: http-status-code-404

Recently I launched a WordPress site (Note: inmotion linux server) with Gravity Forms (GFrom). The site uses a GFrom as a job application and has an input for users to upload their resume.  I have tested it, it works and I can login to the WP Dashboard View and Download all the entries ( in all browsers ) just fine.

After turning things over to the client, they came back to us saying they are unable to view or download the uploaded resumes from the Gravity Forms "Entries" section (Note: the client is able to access both the front and backend of the site, issue seems to only be related to the viewing and or downloading the resumes).  They get a 404 error. Now the weird thing is, the 404 error they are getting was part of their old site on a completely different server (Note: Non WP on a godaddy windows server).  They have tried clearing their browser cache and no success.  Does anyone know what can cause this?

Comment: Is it by any chance possible that the name/url of the new site is the same as the new one and the client has an entry in the hosts-file mapping to the old IP ? In addition, could you clarify the question as it's not clear if the client is unable to access the new site completely or only downloading the resumes causes the 404.

Comment: The client is able to see the new site and login to the dashboard.  At this point it appears they are only having this issue when attempting to view or download the resumes form the gravity forms "Entries" sections and the notification email sent to the admin with the download link.

Comment: Not sure about that as I just searched for how Grav.Forms handles DB-Requests (without any luck for configuring DB-connection). Best thing would be to check with e.g. Firebug net panel where the request ends up when the client clicks "Entries". Somewhere there has to be a kind of redirect to the old server, should be possible to track when this happens. Sounds weird as old site was no WP and I guess you set up new MySQL DB with Grav.Forms for the new entries instead of pulling from the old one, in case they already had DB.